# How I get a content with selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I need to pick up the 33 number in this font, how can I get it with selenium python and store it in a variable?

`<font style="vertical-align: inherit;">33</font>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the font element in the usual way by xpath, then get its text with .text:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, [xpath]).text
```